# Disk Management showing all disks failed and extra spots after replacing a disk

Tags: software-raid

Hello I work for a small company and one of our departments backs up all of their data onto a HP NAS with 4 x 3TB HDDS in a software RAID5 configuration running windows 7 64bit. We recently had one of the disks fail where in Disk Management it was listed as "errors" and all the other disks were listed as "at risk"

We shut down the NAS and replaced the disk with a new 3TB HDD and now Disk Management is showing all of the disks saying failed and has also added some extra spots in that say either "Dynamic" or "Missing" does this mean that a second disk has failed? Or did we do something wrong in the process of updating the raid?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as we do not have a backup to get this data back. Thanks in advance!

Here is a screenshot of what we see in Disk Management

[image: Server Manager - Disk Management]